# Microsoft Secure Score API - service value

Tags: security, microsoft-graph-api

While using the SecureScore API, there is a data value called "service" that contains a code that represents a servie provided by Microsoft.

e.g.
**"service": "EXO",**
"threats": [],
"tier": "Core",
"userImpact": "High",

or
"service": "Azure ATP",
"service": "AppG",
"service": "MCAS",

AppG = App Governance
MCAS = Microsoft Defender for Could Apps

I am trying to find an API that could provide the code and a human friendly name, but running out of options. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am unable to find an API with this information